# Shiny app that changes depending on the time option chosen

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I would like to create a shiny chart app that changes depending on the time window selected. In the code I am pasting I use a bar (slider) that allows you to scroll and select the chosen range of values and it works.

However, I would like to have a sort of selectInput with the following value options per week: **a) First 4 weeks b) First 8 weeka c) First 12 weeks d)First 16 weeks e) Whole period (176 weeks)** and I would like the graph to change depending on the option chosen. I just can't achieve this. I am attaching my code that I use with the slider instead of the answer selection.

```
ui <- fluidPage( column(4,
                          helpText("Time window of interest"),
                                        
                                sliderInput("range1", label = "Selected weeks:",
                                            min = min(df$week), max = max(df$week), value = c(min(df$week), max(df$week)))
                                 ),
                                 
                mainPanel(
                           plotOutput("sp")
                                 )))
                

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output$sp <- renderPlot({
  df2<-df[df$week>=input$range1[1] & df$week<=input$range1[2],]
  ggplot(df2,aes(x = week, y = rate))+
    labs(x = "Week", y = "Incidence Rate", title = "Incidence event rate",
         subtitle = "Stratified by event") + xlim(c(input$range1[1], input$range1[2]))+ geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +style
   })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `radioButton` instead of sliderInput.  Also, please post a sample `df` object so that someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the UI code you need to add select input as per the below

```
selectInput(inputId="week_selection", "Weeks of interest", choices = c("4", "8", "12", "16", "176"), selected = "176")
```

in the server side you need to add an observeEvent to record the user selection in then filter the data for the time period selected

```
observeEvent(input$week_selection, { 
output$sp <- renderPlot({
  df2<-df[df$week<=input$week_selection]
  ggplot(df2,aes(x = week, y = rate))+
    labs(x = "Week", y = "Incidence Rate", title = "Incidence event rate",
         subtitle = "Stratified by event") + xlim(c(input$range1[1], input$range1[2]))+ geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +style
   })
  
}
```

Try this code.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you, your programs work and are very helpful!

Comment: You are more than welcome @Bibi

Answer (score 0):

The following code might give you some inspiration on how to achieve this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(week=1:20,rate=jitter(1:20))  # some fake data

ui <- fluidPage( column(4,
                        helpText("Time window of interest"),
                         # this is probably the interesting part                       
                        selectInput("range2",label = "Selected weeks",
                                    choices = list('4 weeks'=4,
                                                   '8 weeks'=8,
                                                   '12 weeks'=12))
),

mainPanel(
  plotOutput("sp")
))


server <- function(input, output){
  
  output$sp <- renderPlot({
    df2<-df[df$week<=as.numeric(input$range2),] # choosing data points to plot
    print(df2)  # will print the dataframe into console so that you can check what will be plotted
    ggplot(df2,aes(x = week, y = rate))+
      labs(x = "Week", y = "Incidence Rate", title = "Incidence event rate",
           subtitle = "Stratified by event") + xlim(c(input$range1[1], input$range1[2]))+ 
      geom_smooth(method="lm",se = FALSE)  # I changed the smoothing method for the example to work as I don't know your real data frame
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```